# Windows batch: create timestamp from string

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

I want to delete any files that are older than a certain, arbitrary date (which date I wish to designate manually in my code).

How can I get the timestamps of the files concerned and **compare them** with my arbitrary date? I know I can get the timestamps with something like:

```
for %%f in (./*) do echo %%~tf
```

...and I can compare strings or numbers with `gtr` and `lss`, but I can't very well compare the timestamps as strings (because they'd be compared alphabetically instead of chronologically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FORFILES with the /D option. (type `FORFILES /?` from a command prompt for help).

For example, the following will delete all files from the current directory that have not been modified since March 1, 2011:

```
forfiles /d -3/1/2011 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @file"
```

It is possible to work with dates returned by `%%~tf`, but it is a royal pain; especially if you want your solution to work on multiple machines, possibly with different date format settings.